# How to create a structure initialized with default values?

Tags: struct, initialization, vala

How to create a structure that already has default values?
Somehow like this:

```
struct First {
    int data = 4;
    int pos = 5;
    }

void main () {
    var a = First ();
    assert(a.data == 4);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response from AlThomas:

"Structs in Vala can have initializers (similar to a constructor for a class) and methods. So what I can extract from your second pastebin you could write that as:"

```
struct First {
    int data;
    int pos;

    public First (int[] mass) {
        data= 5;
        pos = mass.length;
    }

    public int sas () {
        return data + pos;
    }
}

void main () {
    int[] a = {1,3,0,1,2,3,2,1};
    var b = First (a);
    print (@"$(b.sas ())\n");
}
```